# How to show a sequence is monotonically decreasing and a null sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

For example Let the sequence be $a_n=\frac{n+1}{n^2}$. I proved that $a_n$ is a null sequence by factoring out the $n^2$ .My question is how do i prove that it is monotonically decreasing? . Do i find the limit of the ratio of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ to infinity. Or do i show that $a_n$ is Cauchy ?

Comment: What is a null sequence?

Comment: a sequence whose limit to infinty is 0

Comment: `how do i prove that it is monotonically decreasing` By definition, just prove that $a_{n+1} \le a_n\,$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing
$$
a_n=\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}, \qquad n\ge1,
$$ one sees that $\{a_n\}$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$ being the sum of two monotonically decreasing sequences to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

we compute $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{n+2}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{n+1}{n^2}=\frac{n^2(n+2)-(n+1)^3}{n^2(n+1)^2}=-\frac{n^2+3n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}<0$$